# How would I change text color based on cell value across all tabs using Apps Script

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets

I currently have a function running that fills in the background color based on a word/string in each cell of column B across 20 tabs. It is very useful and eliminates having extensive conditional formatting for each of those tabs. I was able to achieve this thanks to a human named Connor on here. They were a huge help. Now that this awesome function is running, the text is defaulting to black and can make it hard to read with against the background color.

I think it would be best to have a separate function to run this based on input values.

https://i.stack.imgur.com/6rmYF.png

I haven't tried anything, just hoping someone here will have some advice. I know that Key Value pairs is a thing so maybe that can be the fix?

Example:

IF("COGNAC":WhiteText), etc...

Okay well thanks for any help.

Current code/script in play:

```
function changeBackgroundColor() {
  var colorMap = { 
    "ACORN": "#5b0f00", "AP ACORN": "#5b0f00",
    "ALMOND": "#e6a768", "AP ALMOND": "#e6a768",
    "ANJOU": "#9bad2b", "AP ANJOU": "#9bad2b",
    "AQUA": "#406965", "AP AQUA": "#406965",
    "AVOCADO": "#38761d", "AP AVOCADO": "#38761d",
    "BADLANDS": "#682309", "AP BADLANDS": "#682309",
    "BELUGA": "#d9d9d9", "AP BELUGA": "#d9d9d9",
    "BLACK": "#000000", "AP BLACK": "#000000",
    "BOUGAINVILLEA": "#7c0d3e", "AP BOUGAINVILLEA": "#7c0d3e",
    "BOYSENBERRY": "#97104c", "AP BOYSENBERRY": "#97104c",
    "BUBBLEGUM": "#ff74a2", "AP BUBBLEGUM": "#ff74a2",
    "CACAO": "#633f2a", "AP CACAO": "#633f2a",
    "CANYON": "#965a1b", "AP CANYON": "#965a1b",
    #Etc...
};
  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActive();
  var shtnames = ss.getSheets().map(sh => sh.getName());//this gets sheet names
  shtnames.forEach(function (name) {
    var sheet = ss.getSheetByName(name);
    var range = sheet.getRange("B1:B" + sheet.getLastRow());
    var vs = range.getDisplayValues().flat();
    vs.forEach((e,i) => {
      let cv = vs[i].trim();
      let bg = colorMap[cv];
      if(bg) {
        range.getCell(i+1,1).setBackground(bg)
      }
    });
  });
}
```

https://i.stack.imgur.com/uYs92.png

Comment: I have to apologize for my poor English skill. Unfortunately, I cannot understand your question. What are your showing image and `IF("COGNAC":WhiteText), etc...`? In order to correctly understand your question, can you provide the sample input and output situations you expect? First, I would like to correctly understand your question.

Comment: I am not sure how to expand on what I need. I am currently using Conditional Formatting across these 20 tabs to have the cells fill with color and choose text color based on a specific string. There are 28 +or- dynamic rules to achieve this over the 20 different tabs. This is rather cumbersome and makes our very large spreadsheet slow.
The goal is that if a cell in Column B has the word Cognac, I want that cell to have the text turn white. 
IF (in range B:B)
 cell = Cognac
 then font = white
If (in range B:B)
 cell = BLACK
 then font = white
Etc.
Hope that helps.

Comment: Thank you for replying. I apologize for my poor English skill again. Unfortunately, I couldn't understand the relationship between the background colors of cells and the font colors. Can you provide the detail of it?

Answer (score 0):

- Change the object `colorMap` to an array and include the font colour as an array value.
- Use `indexOf` to locate colour values within `ColorMap`
- Use `.setFontColor(fontColr)` to change the font colour.

---

```
function changeBackgroundColor() {
  var colorMap = [ 
    ["ACORN","#5b0f00","#FFFFFF"], 
    ["AP ACORN","#5b0f00","#7FB3D5"],
    ["ALMOND","#e6a768","#EBEDEF"]
  ]
  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActive();
  var shtnames = ss.getSheets().map(sh => sh.getName());//this gets sheet names
  shtnames.forEach(function (name) {
    var sheet = ss.getSheetByName(name);  
    var range = sheet.getRange("B1:B" + sheet.getLastRow());
    var vs = range.getDisplayValues().flat();
    // Logger.log(vs) // DEBUG

    // convert colorMap to a ID array
    var colors =  colorMap.map(function(e){return e[0];});
    // Logger.log(colors) // DEBUG
    
    // loop through the values in Column B
    for (var i=0;i<vs.length;i++){
      let color = vs[i].trim()
      let index = colors.indexOf(color);
      // Logger.log("DEBUG: colour = "+color+", index = "+index)
      if (index == -1){
        // colour not found, do nothing
        return
      }else{
        // Logger.log("DEBUG: index <> -1 so update colours")
        let bgColr = colorMap[index][1]
        let fontColr = colorMap[index][2]
        // Logger.log("DEBUG: bg = "+bgColr+", font = "+fontColr)
        // Logger.log("DEBUG: range = "+range.getCell(i+1,1).getA1Notation())
        range.getCell(i+1,1).setBackground(bgColr).setFontColor(fontColr);
      }
    }
  })
}
```

---

**SAMPLE - Before**

[image: before]

**SAMPLE - After**

[image: after]